# How can I create a correct 2D char array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
char **create_2darray(int rows, int cols){
    char **a;
    a = new char *[rows];
    for(int i;i<rows;i++){
        a[i]=new char[cols];
    }
    return a;
}
char **set_2darry(int rows, int cols, char** array){
    char ** a = array;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++){
            a[i][x]= '0';
        /* here is the problem */
        }
    }
    return a;
}

struct GOL{
    char** table;
    int gen;
    int rows;
    int cols;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    GOL game;
    char** table2= create_2darray(20, 40);
    game.table = set_2darry(20, 40 , table2);
    cout<< game.table;


    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a 2D array using different functions because thats what my professor needs us do but it seems like didn't work..
How can I revise it, or what is wrong with it?

Comment: "it seems like didn't work", how informative.

Comment: Do you mean you're not writing to the array correctly? Or you're getting a segfault?

Comment: Many C++ compilers have an optional compilation switch that enables extra warnings and diagnostics. I'm certain that if you were to try that, your compiler will tell you exactly what's wrong with the third line of the create_2darray() function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

`for (int i; i<rows; i++)`

Since `i` isn't initialized, your program will do something but that doesn't mean it will be what you expect. Decent compilers will even tell you that.